# While do loop in Unix bash shell

Tags: bash, unix, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to create a script which loops in for a list of dates in a file and does a certain operation. My code looks as below. I am using bash shell.

```
while read line; do
#do something with $line
done < file.txt
```

Till now I tried to test my script with 2 dates, but the script executes for the first date but not the second. Also, my script says it completed successfully. Can some please help me here.

Now I am trying to run my script for 4 dates. I have also read someone has a similar issue where there are N lines but the script goes fine for N-1 only. But I couldn't find a perfect answer for that question.

Comment: what is `$file.txt` ?

Comment: the loop is correct. Check using `file $file.txt` that it doesn't contain any windows line-endings

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code that you posted. Please edit your question to show what you're doing inside the loop, and what is contained in the input file.

Comment: Do you have any backslash characters in your file? If so, you may want to use the `-r` option to tell `read` not to interpret these as escapes, as in `while read -r line; do`. In general, when reading files line by line with `read`, you should use `-r`. That is, unless you *want* bash to treat backslashes in your input file as the beginning of an escape sequence.

Comment: Fredrik Pihl, I really have only two lines in my file.txt. it contains the list of dates I want to iterate. The format is DDMMYYYY. So I don't have any spaces also in between the characters. I even looked in notepad++ with line numbers and have only 2 lines.

Comment: karakfa file.txt contains the list of dates that I want to iterate in.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it and this structure of code is fine.
Maybe the problem is inside the loop?

```
[ohad@OhadLaptop]$ cat a.txt 
a
b
c
[ohad@OhadLaptop]$ while read line; do echo $line; done < a.txt 
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line should have a newline at the end. I will show a wrong file:

```
printf "1\n2" > file.txt
wc -l file.txt
1 file.txt
while read line; do
>   echo $line
> done < file.txt
1
```

Is this your problem? Just `cat file.txt`. When the last line and the command prompt are on the same line, you need to append a new line to your file.txt (something like `echo >> file.txt`).